# Does one have to know Razor Pages to use scaffolded identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I am using Razor Views and MVC as my preferred approach. I am also using individual user accounts. I have run scaffolding to create code connected with Identity management (Login, Register pages, etc.). That scaffolding results with creating Razor Pages, which seems to be a MVVM approach. Is there a way I could scaffold those features using Razor Views, what in turn would support MVC pattern?
I feel like I am mixing approaches due to that scaffolding. Now, when I want to add some feature connected with user profile, I have to write MVVM code, and I would like to use one approach instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, Microsoft changed the Identity stuff when creating a new project a while ago, from classic Razor views to new Razor Pages. But luckily, you can grab all this old stuff from Github, for example [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc).